# Finding each radio group on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple radio groups like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">

<input type="radio" name="length" value="tall">
<input type="radio" name="length" value="short">
```

And so on..

My goal is to find out all the sets of radio groups that are on the page. So in this case, it would return `sex, length`

So far I am able to get all of the input's, but I am not sure where to go from here.

```
var radio_groups = [];
$("input[type=radio]").each(function(e){
    //get the name
    var name = this.attr('name');
});
```

Comment: You are already getting the `name` of the input group. I'm confused; what do you want to do next?

Comment: @DavidBrierton My goal is to find out all the sets of radio groups that are on the page. So in this case, it would return `sex, length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is an object that has the names as keys can do:

```
var radios ={};
$("input[type=radio]").each(function(e){
    radios[this.name] = true;
});

console.dir(radios);
/* if want to convert to array */
var radioArray= Object.keys(radios);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5exgw5k/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, this kept it simple. Is it more taxing to overwrite a group name or checking if it exists?

Comment: Doubtful there is any significant difference

Comment: Note that you'll need to bring your own implementation of `keys()` -- or replace it with a `for` loop -- if you want this to work on IE8 or earlier. `Object.keys()` didn't show up until IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf()` to check whether you've already seen the name:

```js
var radio_groups = [];

$("input[type=radio]").each(function(e) {
  var name = $(this).attr('name');

  if (radio_groups.indexOf(name) < 0)
    radio_groups.push(name);
});

console.log(radio_groups);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">

<input type="radio" name="length" value="tall">
<input type="radio" name="length" value="short">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector selects all input elements withe name attribute starting with group, it doesn't filter out unique names

If you want to print only different group names then

```
var group = {};
$('input[name=*][type="radio"]').each(function (index) {
    var name = this.name;
    var elemValue = $(this).val();
    if (!group[name]) {
        group[name] = true;
        console.log(elemValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: waste of DOM search to get name from `this` then make a jQuery selector out of it, what's wrong with `$(this).val()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the checkboxes you might want to consider wrapping the radio's in a form tag. like so:

```
<form id="f1">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
    <input type="radio" name="length" value="tall">
    <input type="radio" name="length" value="short">
</form>
```

Then you can get the value for each like so:

```
var lenghtVal = document.forms[0].length.value;
var sexVal = document.forms[0].sex.value;
```

Replace the index of the forms array according to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/76bhs444/1/

hit f12 and view it in the console. This should be what your looking for.

```
// get all radio names
  var radio_groups = $("input[type=radio]").map(function(e){
    return $(this).attr('name');
  }).get();
  console.log(radio_groups);
// filter duplicates
  radio_groups = $.grep(radio_groups, function(value, index) {
    return $.inArray(value, radio_groups) === index;
  });
  console.log(radio_groups);
```